# New to Appium -trying to run the server

Tags: android, appium-desktop

This is the error i get when i start the server:

the desired capabilities that i passed is :

{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "deviceName": "Android Emulator",
  "app": "C:\Users\Riy\Downloads\WhatsApp Messenger_v2.19.352_apkpure.com.apk"
}

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\Riyan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm install /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/5c88e893aae43fc4303dfa067a6f9b6600ab7e31.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]'; Code: '1'